# Erro java Script no modo desgin em phpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Quando tento salvar a organização de uma estrutura de tabelas, usando o modo design no *Myadmin*, recebo um "fatal error java Script".
Ou seja, sempre que abro esta ferramenta, as tabelas surgem todas desorganizadas, sobrepostas, o que torna impraticável o registo de ligações

Já experimentei diferentes browsers, limpei as caches, reinstalei o *Myadmin* e nada. continua igual. O erro não tem nenhum código identificativo. o Log gerado é:

```
"pma_version": "4.6.4",
"browser_name": "IE",
"browser_version": 11,
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAPBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
"locale": "pt",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "5.6.25",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "callers",
    "name": "DataError",
    "message": "DataError",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": 235,
            "func": "",
            "context": [
                "                lastException = null;",
                "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                "            }",
                "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                "",
                "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                "    return report;"
            ],
            "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "removeAttr",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "",
            "context": null,
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "dispatch",
            "line": 369,
            "column": "",
            "context": null,
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "removeAttr",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "",
            "context": null,
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; GWX:DOWNLOADED; GWX:RESERVED; MAPBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    "incomplete": "false",
    "partial": "true",
    "uri": "db_designer.php?"
},
"script_name": "db_designer.php",
"microhistory": null
```

}

Alguma ideia?